# Openpyxl cell.value with $

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a cell with a string XXXX$YYY and cell.value only returns XXXX
Is there a way to get the literal $ and not treat it as a end of line?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with either cell format type 'General' or 'Text'. Both produce ```cell.value``` as ```XXXX$YYY```.

Comment: The underlying xlsx has the format as Text, but when I check that cell it's number_format = @ (not too familiar if that is a cause of this issue)

The document is being opened as read only

Comment: I get the same: cells of type 'Text' have ```number_format``` as ```@```. I don't really know what's causing your issue. Maybe update openpyxl to the latest version and see if it's fixed.

Comment: This sounds like some kind of special formatting. In openpyxl you get the value. You can try implementing the OOXML formatting specification if you like.

Comment: From the docs "Text placeholder. If text is typed in the cell, the text from the cell is placed in the format where the at symbol (@) appears. [Example: If the number format is "Bob "@" Smith" (including quotation marks), and the value "John" is in the cell, the value Bob John Smith is displayed. end example]"

Comment: The issue was outside of openpxl - thanks for having a look all